# center an image in div vertically and horizontally

Tags: css, html, image

I found my tuts about centering image horizontally and vertically . But it is not working . 
my code are

```
#parent {
    position : relative;
    float : left;
    width : 700px;
    height : 400px;
    overflow : hidden;
    background-color: black;
}


#parent img {
    max-height :400px;
    max-width : 700px;
}
```

The height and width of image is dynamic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write like this:

```
#parent {
    position : relative;
    float : left;
    width : 700px;
    height : 400px;
    overflow : hidden;
    background-color: black;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:400px;
}


#parent img {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Check this  http://tinkerbin.com/XYKUzvXu

**UPDATED**

Check this http://tinkerbin.com/GL4GaNfo

Comment: I think this actually works regardless of the image size, check the demo out

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame put any image inside that & it will be in center

Comment: As far as I can tell, this actually works completely. I've not seen vertical-align used like this before . . .

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame first try your self.

Comment: @sandeep I can not get the height and size of img . If there any way to center an image without defining height and width.

Comment: @DiptopolDam above example works. Check this updated link  http://tinkerbin.com/GL4GaNfo

Comment: @iambriansreed -1 to you, this worked flawlessly with unknown image dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

You should have

```
text-align: center
```

on the #parent style to align the image horizontally, if I'm remembering correctly, you can also set this on the parent style:

```
line-height: 400px;
```

and this will align the image vertically.

Comment: This won't work either. The question says that the height of the image is dynamic.

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame: What are you talking about? Read the first two comments on this answer.

Comment: Using `display:table-cell;` is terribly hacky, @thirtydot.

Comment: @thirtydot The OP set a max-height and max-width. This will work fine.

Comment: Actually I think @thirtydot is right . . . and this is my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
#parent {
    position : relative;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    width : 700px;
    height : 400px;
    overflow : hidden;
    background-color: black;
}


#parent img {
    max-height :400px;
    max-width : 700px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a syntax error `nax-width : 700px;` should be `max-width : 700px;`. Any ways use this CSS, it will work, yours won't.

```
#parent
{
   position : relative;
    float : left;
    display: table-cell;
    width : 700px;
    height : 400px;
    overflow : hidden;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#parent img
{
    max-height :400px;
    max-width : 700px;
}​
```

Ex here http://jsfiddle.net/ANwmv/

Comment: I don't think vertical-align: middle, works in this case unfortunately

Comment: That won't work. `vertical-align: middle` does not work how you think it does.

Comment: @thirtydot Made changes, forgot display:table-cell.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle` and `text-align:center`

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
  <img src="http://s3.buysellads.com/1241308/100953-1333587587.jpg
"></div>
```

**Css**

```
#parent {
    position : relative;
    display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
    width : 700px;
    height : 400px;
    overflow : hidden;
    background-color: black;
  text-align:center;
}


#parent img {
    max-height :400px;
    max-width : 700px;
}
```

Live demo

http://tinkerbin.com/RDZuJFS7

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can get your desired results through `display:table-cell;` `vertical-align:middle;` & `text-align:center;` 
 see the below code :-

**HTML**

```
 <div id="parent">
      <img src="http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-107x160-RedDots.jpg" />
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parent {
    display:table-cell;
    width : 700px;
    height : 400px;
    background-color: black;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}


#parent img {
    width : 107px;
    height : 160px;
}
```

see the demo :- http://tinkerbin.com/ajsaa856

Comment: its really ridiculous i think he is not checking the answers everybody is giving relevant answer's from their side if he has problem so ask us......