# How to center an image both vertically and horizontally in a div

Tags: html, css

How do I set the position of an image to be in the center of a div (both vertically and horizontally). I can make it horizontally center, but how to center it vertically?

N.B: height and width of the images may change.

html:

```
{% for photo in photos %}
<div class="thumbnail_container">
    <a class='gallery' href='{{MEDIA_URL}}{{photo.image}}'><img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{photo.image}}" class="thumbnail"></a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
<span class="clear_left"></span>
```

css:

```
.thumbnail_container {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}

.thumbnail {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    max-width: 240px;
    max-height: 190px;
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359942/center-an-image-in-div-vertically-and-horizontally?rq=1

Comment: M sorry, but didn't helped. All the images got jumbled up in one single div.

Answer (score 3):

Try to make parent container CSS like this:

```
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
```

Try this class:

```
.thumbnail_container{
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    border:1px solid; 
    padding: 0px;   
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    display: table-cell; 
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Try jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U9EjM/3/)

Comment: But, I don't want that much of space between the image and the div. So, I changed the height/width to max-height/max-width, and I increased the dimensions of the img. After the preferred spacing between the image and the div, the vertical alignment again looses it center position. Please check it - http://jsfiddle.net/Robinlery/njbdS/

Comment: @Robin this is the perfect way to center - [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19108967/1542290)

Answer (score 0):

```
.thumbnail_container
{
    border:2px solid red;
    height:400px;
    width:500px;
    text-align:center;
}
a img
{
    margin-top:15%;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U9EjM/)

Comment: Your demo does seems great. But my images are all coming out of the div downside!

Comment: @Robin why don't you make a fiddle.

Comment: Some of it are displaying well, but some are coming down of the div. Please check on it - http://jsfiddle.net/Robinlery/F6CsN/.

Comment: But they are loosing its aspect ratio. Do i specify the max-height and width for that?

Comment: @Robin check out http://jsfiddle.net/F6CsN/1/, they are now keeping aspect  ratio

Comment: @Mr.Alien The problem is that the image size may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use transform to do this trick, it will be always in the center

```
.thumbnail_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #444;
}

.thumbnail {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/UlOsixI/1/)

EDIT:

Add this as a fallback in a separate css file to target IE want to support it

```
.thumbnail {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: -40px; /* 80px/2 */
  margin-top: -40px;

}
```

You can target IE in this way in your html file and add your css in ie.css

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ie.css">
<![endif]-->
```

So ie.css will be run on any browser less than ie9, so we can use 'translate' for modern browsers in our main style and still support old ones.

Comment: Is there any other way around for IE <=8?

Comment: Thanks! But how do I target IE? I tried, but all the images got shrinked... Will you please elaborate. And I am using max-height and max-width, will it still be valid?